# Downsides to Property Tax Deferral?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, property-taxes, illinois

Illinois has a property tax deferral program that allows seniors to borrow against the equity of their house (which includes a lien) up to $5K per year at 6% simple interest (!).  I am considering having my mother take advantage of this program.

https://www.dupageco.org/Treasurer/1863/

Assuming that:

- She qualifies
- She will eventually need access to the equity in her house (via sale, mortgage, reverse mortgage, or some other loan)
- She is getting close to the point where she may need to start accessing that equity

do you see any downsides to using this program, or any better options?

Comment: Surely a cash-out refi would be better? You'd get a tax-deductible interest rate of around 3.8%, compared to 6%.

Comment: 3.8% on a large sum will be much more in interest than 6% on $5K.  Plus since she is asset-rich and income poor I would imagine it would be difficult to get a mortgage.